# Can chrome extension context menu (for links) extract the link content before it popups up?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a context menu item depending on what the context link is.

For instance, I want to display "AAA" for a link that starts with "https://www.google.com" and "BBB" for a link that starts with "https://twitter.com".

```
var context_twitter_search = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title":'AAA', // This is what I want to change depending on the info.linkUrl.
  "contexts":["link"],
  "onclick":function(info, tab) {
    var target_content = '';
    target_content = info.linkUrl; // I can ONLY get the content after right-click.
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"https://twitter.com/search?q="+target_content});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your background script:

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
    let tp = info.menuItemId;
    let url = info.linkUrl;
    switch (tp) {
        case 'AAA':
            alert('hi google user');
            break;
        case 'BBB':
            alert('hi Tweeter user');
            break;
    }
}

function handleInstalled(details) {
    var contextMenuItem = [
        {
            "id": "AAA",
            "title": "AAA",
            "contexts": ["link"],
            "targetUrlPatterns": ["https://*.google.com/*"]
        }, {
            "id": "BBB",
            "title": "BBB",
            "contexts": ["link"],
            "targetUrlPatterns": ["https://*.twitter.com/*"]
        }
    ];
    let cmi;
    for (let k = 0; k < contextMenuItem.length; k++) {
        cmi = contextMenuItem[k];
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
                "id": cmi.id,
                "title": cmi.title,
                "contexts": cmi.contexts,
                "enabled": true,
                "targetUrlPatterns": cmi.targetUrlPatterns
            }, () => {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {}
                else {}
            })
    }
    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler)
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(handleInstalled);
```